# how to put intermediate values on UISLIDER between minimum and maximum values

Tags: ios, uislider

i have a UISlider with minimum value 0 and maximum value 100. I need to display intermediate values between 0-100 like 10,20,30...90 on slider. Please advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add Labels as subviews to the UISlider:

```
- (void)addLabelsToSlider:(UISlider*)slider{
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i+=10){
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [label sizeToFit];
        CGFloat labelX = (slider.frame.size.width/10)*i/10;
        CGFloat labelY = slider.frame.size.height-label.frame.size.height/2;
        label.center = CGPointMake(labelX, labelY);

        [slider addSubview:label];
    }
}
```